# Xpath syntax correction

Tags: ios, xml, xpath

im trying to use gdata to read this xml file:
ftp://ftp2.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10753.xml

the path is //product/forecast/area aac="VIC_PT025" description="Geelong" type="location" parent-aac="VIC_PW007"

what is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to select only 1 `area` element?

If so, `area` element with attribute "aac" with value "VIC_PT025" looks unique in the document so you should be good with `//product/forecast/area[@aac="VIC_PT025"]`

If you want to test all attributes you can use `//product/forecast/area[@aac="VIC_PT025" and @description="Geelong" and @type="location" and @parent-aac="VIC_PW007"]`

Answer (score 0):

Syntax

//product/forecast/area[@aac="VIC_PT025" and @description="Geelong" and @type="location" and @parent-aac="VIC_PW007"]